# fwrite() function not working

Tags: php

So this is my code:

```
<?php
$path = 'logs/' . date("Y:m:d") . '.txt';

$get = $_POST['data']; // I know this is insecure, don't worry
$file = fopen($path, 'w') or die("Something is wrong with your file permissions, please obtain the nessecary rights!");
fwrite($file, $get) or die('error writing to file');    
?>
```

the `fopen()` function works fine, I don't get any error whatsoever. The problem is that I get an "`error writing to file`" meaning there is something wrong with my `fwrite()` function.

What could be the problem here?

I'm using apache2 and php7.

Comment: Probably because `:` is not a valid character in a file name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wouldn't work because of the name of your file name as in:

```
$path = 'logs/' . date("Y:m:d") . '.txt';
```

As you will notice, your generated path is going to be something like: *`logs/2016:12:18.txt`* implying that the name of your **`.txt`** file is **`2016:12:18`** which isn't a valid name as a file name CANNOT contain a colon (**`:`**).

*Please note; the following characters cannot be used when naming files:*

- < (less than)
- > (greater than)
- : (colon)
- " (double quote)
- / (forward slash)
- \ (backslash)
- | (vertical bar or pipe)
- ? (question mark)
- * (asterisk)

*... read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename).*

You should amend to an acceptable file name so as to get it working.

Below is an example, using hyphen (**`-`**) as delimiter:

```
$path = 'logs/' . date("Y-m-d") . '.txt'; // Expected result: logs/2016-12-18.txt
```

Comment: You can on non-windows systems right? Actually, the file got created just fine. The problem was that I forgot i needed to use a POST request. Whoops. I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @David: You may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1976007/6381711) post helpful as well.